# Is there a way to target a specific worker in pm2 in cluster mode?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I think the title is pretty straight forward but if I start my node app in cluster-mode then is it possible to target a specific worker during request?
I'm aware that the load is balanced in `round-robin` fashion by default in `pm2` but I'm just wondering if this is even possible.
I'm attempting this because I have a worker that's running in `debug` mode and wanted to forward it's request to `node-inspector` for remote debugging (I'm not sure if this is even possible yet).

Comment: May be you can reduce your cluster size to a single process. This way all traffic will hit the desired destination (the debugged process)

Comment: what specific target ? you can all manage in your server side code

Comment: @yeiniel part of my idea was to let other workers run as is (no debug mode) so that it keeps running in cluster mode while I just target one specific instance but if that's not viable then I'd have to resort to your option.

Comment: @shriek i don't event know howto to make one of the process instances to go into debug mode without the others doing the same.  So if you have found a solution for that can you share it here for reference? Have a good day.

Comment: @yeiniel I haven't verified this yet (which is part of the reason why I'm posting this question) but you can start another instance by doing `pm2 start myapp -n debugapp --node-args="--debug" -i 1` which spawns `myapp` as `debugapp` name.

Comment: Yes but i think it will not join debugapp to an existing myapp cluster. It just will create a new single process cluster.

Comment: You're probably right. Wish there was a way to verify which cluster it's part of.